# How to get the data and bss address space in run time (In Unix C program)

Tags: c, unix

I need to get the address space of bss and data section of the DATA segment during run time. I need the start and end address of each section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the address range of the data segment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308996/finding-the-address-range-of-the-data-segment)

Answer (score 6):

The terminology "data segment" is somewhat obsolete.

On Unix systems, there is a supposedly portable way to retrieve the *end* address: simply call `brk`.  However, the `brk` function comes with a warning.  From the man pages:

> **The brk and sbrk functions are historical curiosities left over from earlier days before the advent of virtual memory management.**

Emphasis original.

**If you use ELF:**  If you know you are using ELF binaries, that information is more or less ignored when your program is loaded.  ELF programs are loaded by *segments,* but `.data` and `.bss` are *sections.*  The `.data` and `.bss` sections are in the same segment, but that segment also has other sections (`.ctors`, `.dtors`, `.got`, etc.).

**If you use Linux:** If you know that you are using Linux specifically, then you can do the following:

1. Read the ELF headers from your executable.  You can use `/proc/self/exe` to find your executable.
2. Read the memory maps from `/proc/self/maps`.
3. For the maps that correspond to your file, you can figure out which map corresponds to the `.data` section by looking at the offsets.

**If you are using `glibc`:** The symbol `__data_start` points to the beginning of the data section, and I think I've seen `__bss_start` defined as well.

```
extern char __data_start;
extern char __bss_start;
void *get_data_start(void) { return &__data_start; }
```

**But...** what are you trying to accomplish?  It's most productive to explain *why* you want to know where the sections are.  Are you writing a garbage collector?  A debugger?  Do you want to save process images?

**Word of warning:** Who knows when any of the above things will break.  Maybe `__data_start` isn't defined, or maybe `brk` points to some unrelated region of memory.  Reading the ELF headers seems like the most reliable trick, and there are libraries for it too.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps not a satisfactory answer, but under linux, you can use /proc/self/exe which <strike>contains</strike> is a symlink to your process image.