# Detecting error in Number of Solutions in N-Queens Problem

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, backtracking, bitmask, n-queens

### Programming [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens-ii/) Description

> The **n-queens** puzzle is the problem of placing `n` queens on an `n x n` chessboard such that no two queens attack each other. Given an
> integer `n`, return *the number of distinct solutions to the
> **n-queens puzzle***. The `1 ≤ n ≤ 9` are the constraints of Test Cases.

[Taken from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens-ii/)]

---

### My Attempt

I tried to solve the problem using bit-masking. In short, we try all possible combination, and backtrack whenever solution is not possible.

> We place queen **row-by-row**, and with each placement, we restrict some positions/box where remaining queens cannot be placed.

Now, we can identify each **column** by it's `index`, **diagonal** have property of same `row index - column index`, and **anti-diagonal** have property of same `row index + column index`.

Thus, after placing queen at any box, we will restrict columns, diagonals and anti-diagonals  identified by that box. This will be done by having a bit-mask variable for all three parameters.

Here is the code in `c` for the same (which was submitted on Online Judge).

```c
int N;
int count=0;

void rowExpansion(int r, int cols, int diags, int aDiags);

int totalNQueens(int n)
{    
    N=n;
    rowExpansion(0,0,0,0);
    
    return count;
}

void rowExpansion(int r, int cols, int diags, int aDiags)
{   
    if (r<N)
    {
        for (register int c=0; c<N; c++)
        {
            // current Diagonal, current antidiagonal
            int cD = r - c + N, cAd= r + c;
            
            /* Check if (r,c) is valid, Checking ith bits of Three Bit Masks.  
            If any of them is set, don't include this (r,c) */

            if ((cols & (1 << c)) || (diags & (1 << cD)) || (aDiags & (1 << cAd))) 
            continue;
            
            //Next Row traversal with updated bit-masks
            rowExpansion(r+1, cols | 1<<c, diags | 1<<cD, aDiags | 1<<cAd);
        }
    }
    
    else count++;
}
```

This code was working fine on Console, but on submitting it produced error. For `n=1`, code was giving correct output in Console, but giving wrong answer on submitting. I tried to code same technique in `python` and it worked fine.

Attached is the screenshot of error.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the same code with added `main` and other functionalities to make it [**reprex**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it gave correct output on [CodeBlocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int N;
int count=0;

void rowExpansion(int r, int cols, int diags, int aDiags);

int totalNQueens(int n)
{
    N=n;
    rowExpansion(0,0,0,0);

    return count;
}

void rowExpansion(int r, int cols, int diags, int aDiags)
{
    if (r<N)
    {
        for (register int c=0; c<N; c++)
        {
            // current Diagonal, current antidiagonal
            int cD = r - c + N, cAd= r + c;

            /* Check if (r,c) is valid, Checking ith bits of Three Bit Masks.
            If any of them is set, don't include this (r,c) */

            if ((cols & (1 << c)) || (diags & (1 << cD)) || (aDiags & (1 << cAd))) 
            continue;

            //Next Row traversal with updated bit-masks
            rowExpansion(r+1, cols | 1<<c, diags | 1<<cD, aDiags | 1<<cAd);
        }
    }

    else count++;
}

void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter Number of Queens (1-9) : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if (n<1 || n>9)
    {
        printf("Wrong Input!");
    }
    else
    {
        int D[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 10, 4, 40, 92, 352};
        int x = totalNQueens(n);

        printf("Desired Output : %d\nGiven Output   : %d\n", D[n],x);
    }
}
```

As background, I use to practice mostly in `python` and not very much skilled in `c` programming.

---

### Doubt(s)

1. What is the error in this code?  Is the error logical, syntactical or runtime-error?
2. Why it happens that same code on *console* is successful, but fails on *submitting*? Can someone provide good reference for the same?
3. Users in comments blamed Global Variables for the error. Can someone throw more light on why this happen, and provide hint on how to get rid of global variables from this code?

---

Comment: Related? https://oeis.org/A000170

Comment: Link is totally related, @pmg. But question is more about detecting error, and less about N-queens. I am particularly not interested in *number of distinct solution* but interested in why my code is throwing error.

Comment: Maybe check your local runs with the numbers from OEIS. If the results from your local run and the result from the online site differ, (at least) one of the results is wrong (assuming, of course, that OEIS has correct results). Usually, these kind of sites use some hidden input when submitting.

Comment: Maybe your console compiler uses 64-bits integers? Those are very large numbers.

Comment: How big is `n` in those tests?

Comment: The question is from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens-ii/) @pmg. I tried to code same technique in python and it worked fine. So, local run has same answer as OEIS. But it is throwing error in `c`. Interested in finding if error is logical, syntactical or runtime. And what exactly is the error?

Comment: Can you write your code without the global variables `N` and `count`? **Global variables are bad**

Comment: Second that @pmg, **Global Variables should be avoided**. But, I guess I won't be able to write without `count` being global. Moreover, even if they are bad, they should be wrong output on console as well. Then, why on console they are giving correct output but giving wrong on Submission. Can you write answer or provide some good reference for the same *[as rules of site advices to avoid extended conversation on Comments]*?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @RohitSingh: No, it does not. It is not complete. Other people should be able to compile and execute the code with **no** changes or additions. Since there is no `main` routine and no code that calls `totalNQueens`, other people cannot execute the code. We should not have to guess what else you have in the program to make it run. If the software you are using to submit the code takes just the code shown and supplies its own `main`, you need to show the full specification of the assignment so that other people can reproduce how it executes the software.

Comment: I have attempted to add [**reprex**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code in the body. Do check @EricPostpischil

Comment: Can you see the [problem](https://godbolt.org/z/97TTTjboW) caused by that variable beeing global and not resetted?

Comment: Yes, @Bob__ Got the hint. Thanks a Ton! Can you please provide more reference on why it happened, how to reset the variable, and what changes should I make in the solution? Since, site advices to avoid extended conversation on Comments, I request you to write an answer for the same. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is how the variable `count` is used.

```
int N;
int count=0;           // <-- Declaration of count as a GLOBAL variable

void rowExpansion(int r, int cols, int diags, int aDiags);

int totalNQueens(int n)
{
    N=n;
    rowExpansion(0,0,0,0);

    return count;            // <-- Here it's returned
}

void rowExpansion(int r, int cols, int diags, int aDiags)
{
    if (r<N)
    {
        for (register int c=0; c<N; c++)
        {
            // ...

            rowExpansion(r+1, cols | 1<<c, diags | 1<<cD, aDiags | 1<<cAd);
        }
    }
    else count++;  // <-- Here it's modified
}
```

If the function `totalNQueens` is called more than once, it just accumulates the count, because `count` is never resetted.

The OP mention a Python code that "works" as expected, but it's not provided, so we can only guess that it doesn't have this bug.

I'd suggest not to use a global variable, in the first place. The [following](https://godbolt.org/z/s4oPfvfze) is a possible alternative implementation.

Note that I also used an `unsigned` type to perform all the bit manipulations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

long long int rowExpansion( unsigned N
                          , unsigned r
                          , unsigned cols
                          , unsigned diags
                          , unsigned aDiags )
{   
  long long int count = 0;
  if ( r < N )
  {
    for ( unsigned c = 0; c < N; c++ )
    {
      unsigned cD = r - c + N;
      unsigned cAd = r + c;

      if ( (cols & (1u << c)) ||
           (diags & (1u << cD)) || 
           (aDiags & (1u << cAd)) ) 
        continue;

      count += rowExpansion( N, r+1
                           , cols | 1u << c
                           , diags | 1u << cD
                           , aDiags | 1u << cAd );
    }
  }
  else {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}

long long int totalNQueens(int n)
{    
  if ( n < 0 ) {
    return 0;
  }
  if ( (unsigned)n > sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT ) {
    puts("Too big.");
    return 0;
  }
  return rowExpansion(n, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
  // https://oeis.org/A000170
  // 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 10, 4, 40, 92, 352, 724 
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
  {
    printf("%lld\n", totalNQueens(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: @RohitSingh In your snippet, `count` is declared outside of any block. Having [file-scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope#File_scope), by default, it also has [external linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage) and [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration). In your code, all the (recursive) calls of `rowExpansion` access and modify the same global variable. So does `totalNQueens` (and any other function).

Comment: @RohitSingh If that function is called multiple times, it returns the *current* value, but it should reset (assign 0) `count` *before* calling `rowExpansion` again, restarting the calculation.

Comment: And there is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3704864) to reset `count` before calling `rowExpansion` again. Right?

Comment: @RohitSingh Of course you [could](https://godbolt.org/z/5jPE5M97a), but I still suggest to [limit](https://godbolt.org/z/bE1rn7vPE) the scope of your variables as [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176118/when-is-it-ok-to-use-a-global-variable-in-c), instead. Note that the first version of your question didn't include a [mre] and it still contains more than *one* question.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the code with no external variables (`N` and `count`) results in the online judging accepting it.

Comment: (no sarcasm or other offense intended, honest impressed question): Do you have your own account there and actually tried successfully to submit? Or are you referring to a confirmation by OP which I do not see? (me not finding it or it being deleted....) And could you confirm that with globals it is rejected? This would be a new way of convincing competition OPs that proposals for needlessly clean code actually avoid/solve problems.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I created an account and tested with and without external variables.